# SMSC interconnect

Tags: sms-gateway, bulksms

I am curious about SMS aggregators and I would like to get info about build one but I have no point to start getting info. Do you know?

1. Necessary hardware/Software
2. Good SMSCs to start the bussiness
3. Most price-competitive SMSCs
4. Minimum SMS volume to start
5. Any contact/company

Answer (score 0):

To build your own you could probably start by registering to become a PRSP and content provider. Then you could get a short code from a Mobile Service Provider. Connect to the Mobile Service Provider using  [SMPP Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_Message_Peer-to-Peer). 
The Mobile Service Provider should give you cridentials: username passwords etc to connect to them. 
You could then use [Kannel: Open Source WAP and SMS gateway](http://www.kannel.org/) to configure a [value added service gateway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Value-added_service) that you could use to provider sms aggregation services amongst other services such as football updates etc.
You could also host more than one service(client) on the same shortcode/vas gateway.

Comment: for SMPP you have to configure kannel on a linux box preferably and then you could use the kannel config file to connect to the smsc. read the user guide for more info [here](http://www.kannel.org/download/1.4.0/userguide-1.4.0/userguide.html).